# ASP.Net AJAX Control Toolkit AutoCompleteExtender without using Web Services

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm working on Asp.net 4.5 and I implement autocomplete extender without using web services, but it's not working. Here is my code

```
<div>
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers"
MinimumPrefixLength="21"
CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="100"
TargetControlID="TextBox1"
ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
```

here is my aspx code:-

```
  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> SearchCustomers(string prefixText, int count)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=.; database=northwind; integrated security=true";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select name from patientHistory where name like @SearchText +'%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            List<string> customers = new List<string>();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(sdr["name"].ToString());
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            return customers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say it's not working, but you don't provide any further details. Are you getting an error message on the server side or client side? Is your server side function being called at all? Have you used your browser's debug tools and/or Fiddler to see the request and response?

Comment: i use breakpoint its code working fine but auto-complete is not working on the .aspx page

Comment: Your MinimumPrefixLength is 21. That's awfully high. You have to type 21 characters before it activates the auto complete. You still haven't mentioned if youve looked at the request and responses with browser tools or Fiddler.

Comment: This old question appears to have been abandoned without a resolution, and since it also seems to have caused some clarification questions, I think it is appropriate to close it as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `EnablePageMethods` to the scriptmanager

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```